# </form> to PHP to two Mysql tables

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to get the form to send to two different tables in my MySQL, it always stops at my if(!$_POST['submit']) location. I really need your help have been trying different things for almost 24 hours straight.

HTML

```
<form action="php/createhemerb.php" method="post">

            <input  type="text" name="inputName" value="" id=""> </input> </br>
            <input  type="text" name="inputPage" value="http://" id=""> </input> </br>
            <textarea type="text" name="inputComment" value="" id="" size="50" style="height:100px; width:400px;"> </textarea>  
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputFs" value="checked" id=""/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputFsn" value="checked" id=""/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputFsj" value="checked" id=""/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="inputFsjn" value="checked" id=""/>
            <input type="text" name="inputBeS" value="" id="" size="50"> </input>
            <input type="text" name="inputBeK" value="" id="" size="50"> </input>

            <a href="http://digsitesvalue.com/" target="_new"></a><br/><br/>

            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputAll" value="checked" id=""/>Alla
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputKun" value="checked" id=""/>Kundtjänstarbeten
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputByg" value="checked" id=""/>Bygg, Anläggning
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputEko" value="checked" id=""/>Ekonomi, Finans, Försäkring
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputFor" value="checked" id=""/>Försäljning, marknad, reklam
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputHR" value="checked" id=""/>HR, juridik
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputHal" value="checked" id=""/>Hälso-, Sjukvård, Omsorg
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputInd" value="checked" id=""/>Industri, produktion
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputInk" value="checked" id=""/>Inköp, Transport, Logistik
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputIT" value="checked" id=""/>IT, data
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputKon" value="checked" id=""/>Kontor, Administration
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputKul" value="checked" id=""/>Kultur, Media
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputKva" value="checked" id=""/>Kvalitet, miljö
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputMan" value="checked" id=""/>Management
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputPed" value="checked" id=""/>Pedagogiska arbeten
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputSer" value="checked" id=""/>Service, detaljhandel, butik
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputTek" value="checked" id=""/>Teknik, Naturvetenskap
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputBen" value="checked" id=""/>Bemanningsföretag
            </br><input type="checkbox" name="inputOff" value="checked" id=""/>Offentlig sektor

            <input type="text" name="inputFon" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
            <input  type="text" name="inputJob" value="" id="fnid" hidden/>
            <br/><input  type="text" name="inputHem" value="" id="" style="width:300px;"/>          <br/>
            <br/><input  type="text" name="inputPla" value="" id="" style="width:300px;"/>          <br/>
            <br/><textarea name="inputKom" id="" style="height:100px; width:300px;"></textarea> <br/>
            <br/><input type="text" name="inputPri" value="" style="width:100px;" id=""/>sek        <br/>
            <input type="text" name="inputFid" value="" id="idet" hidden/>
            <input hidden type="text" name="inputDat" value="" id="dat" hidden/>
            <input hidden type="text" name="inputabe" value="" id="abe" hidden/>
            <br/><textarea name="inputKth" id="" style="width:300px;"></textarea><br/>  
            <br/><input type="checkbox" name="inputOmk" value="checked" id=""/>

    <input type="submit" value="Button" />

</form>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connection.php';

    // textboxes
$name = $_POST['inputName'];
$desc = $_POST['inputComment'];
$Page = $_POST['inputPage'];
$BeS = $_POST['inputBeS'];
$BeK = $_POST['inputBeK'];
// checkboxes
$fs = $_POST['inputFs'];
$fsn = $_POST['inputFsn'];
$fsj = $_POST['inputFsj'];
$fsjn = $_POST['inputFsjn'];
$Kun = $_POST['inputKun'];
$Byg = $_POST['inputByg'];
$Eko = $_POST['inputEko'];
$For = $_POST['inputFor'];
$HR = $_POST['inputHR'];
$Hal = $_POST['inputHal'];
$Ind = $_POST['inputInd'];
$Ink = $_POST['inputInk'];
$IT = $_POST['inputIT'];
$Kon = $_POST['inputKon'];
$Kul = $_POST['inputKul'];
$Kva = $_POST['inputKva'];
$Man = $_POST['inputMan'];
$Ped = $_POST['inputPed'];
$Ser = $_POST['inputSer'];
$Tek = $_POST['inputTek'];
$Ben = $_POST['inputBen'];
$Off = $_POST['inputOff'];
$All = $_POST['inputAll'];

$Namn = $_POST['inputJob'];
$Hem = $_POST['inputHem'];
$Kom = $_POST['inputKom'];
$Fid = $_POST['inputFid'];
$Dat = $_POST['inputDat'];
$Pri = $_POST['inputPri'];
$Job = $_POST['inputFon'];
$Abe = $_POST['inputabe'];
$Kth = $_POST['inputKth'];
$Omk = $_POST['inputOmk'];
$Pla = $_POST['inputPla'];



if(!$_POST['submit']) {
echo "please fill out the form";
header ('Location: ../index.php '); 

} else {

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO hemsida (`ID`,`Namn`,`Comment`,`Fs`,`Fsn`,`Fsj`,`Fsjn`,`Kon`,`Kul`,`Kva`,`Man`,`Ped`,`Ser`,`Tek`,`Ben`,`Off`,`Kun`,`Byg`,`Eko`,`For`,`HR`,`Hal`,`Ind`,`Ink`,`IT`,`BeS`,`BeK`,`All`,`Page`) 
            VALUES(NULL,'$name','$desc','$fs','$fsn','$fsj','$fsjn','$Kon','$Kul','$Kva','$Man','$Ped','$Ser','$Tek','$Ben','$Off','$Kun','$Byg','$Eko','$For','$HR','$Hal','$Ind','$Ink','$IT','$BeS','$BeK','$All','$Page')") or die(mysql_error());


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO erbjudande (`ID`,`Namn`,`Hem`,`Kom`,`Fid`,`Dat`,`Pri`,`Job`,`abe`,`Kth`,`Omk`,`Pla`) 
            VALUES(NULL,'$Namn','$Hem','$Kom','$Fid','$Dat','$Pri','$Job','$Abe','$Kth','$Omk','$Pla')") or die(mysql_error());

    echo "User has been addad";
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}

?>
```

Comment: On a side note, [mysql_ functions deprecated/data validation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) issues, you could also gorup the checkbox values into an array rather than handling them as seperate variables

Comment: also, you can't send header information using header() after output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a form element *named* "submit", so I wouldn't expect that value to exist in the `$_POST` collection.

POST values are key/value pairs where the key is the name of the form element.  Try assigning a name:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Button" />
```

Comment: Of course. I mistook `<input type="submit" value="Button" />` as being named. I need a 2nd cup of coffee. Plus, a dash of dyslexia doesn't help me neither.

Comment: You guys are awesome, i started with two forms and two php, because i had another form in between, tried everything with javascript and ajax that i could find, now when i was down to one php file and one action i was destroyed when i could not get it to work. THANKS A MILLION! I feel less the brilliant right now.

Comment: $Fid = mysql_query("SELECT ID AS MAX(ID) FROM hemsida;");

Answer (score 0):

$_POST take the name of input

You have to add a name attribute
like this:

```
name = "submit"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add name="submit" and you need to use mysql_real_escape_string function.